# Problem on vector equations

Tags: vectors

If $(b+c)x+(c+a)y+(a+b)z=k=(b-c)x+(c-a)y+(a-b)z$ then what will be the equation of the straight line passing through origin and parallel to given line ?

My attempt:

I tried to relate the direction ratios of the given line and the new line as they are parallel but the problem is that line is passing through origin so I am ending up getting all zeros. Please help. Any hint will do .

Comment: Any hints or suggestions:

Comment: Add and subtract the two expression for $k.$

Comment: After that cross multiplication will do I guess.

Comment: Thanks Saulspatz .

Comment: Saulspatz, is this question of low quality according to you? Please state.

Comment: What did I say about low quality?  Why are you asking me this?

Comment: Saulspatz I know you have not said anything. Actually a message is appearing whenever I am trying to ask a question stating that 'Questions will not be accepted from this account'. When I entered the Help Center , it is showing that the probable reason is that the questions are of low quality. That is why I am asking you because you are Moderator of this site I guess. I am only seeking opinion from you. Please say something regarding the level of the question, whether it suits this site or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a moderator.  The question seems perfectly fine to me.  I wish I knew how to help you, but I don't.  Did you try asking on meta.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Saulspatz , I think an upvote can , to some extent , help me out because I have not received any help from the meta. Can you please upvote the question ? Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Thanks to saulspatz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given straight line is intersection of the planes $ \mathcal{P}_1:\;(b+c)x+(c+a)y+(a+b)z=k$ and $\mathcal{P}_2:\;(b-c)x+(c-a)y+(a-b)z=k.$

Thanks to the coefficients we know that these planes are not parallel. Therefore, the parallel line passing through origin can be defined as intersection of planes parallel to $ \mathcal{P}_1,  \mathcal{P}_2$ passing through origin. It is $$(b+c)x+(c+a)y+(a+b)z=0=(b-c)x+(c-a)y+(a-b)z.$$

**Note added**
The vectors normal respectively to $\mathcal{P}_1,  \mathcal{P}_2$ represent diagonals of a parallelogram. The sides of this parallelogram are represented by the vectors $(b,c,a)$ and $(c,a,b).$ This is why the planes are not parallel.

Comment: Bro I got the answer , thanks anyway